# Warning: 'sandbox' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium. ubuntu 20.04 and vscode version is 1.58

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04

Warning: 'sandbox' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.
Can anyone tell me why this warring occure???

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with VSCode 1.58, am using ubuntu 21.04.
It is an issue with the new vscode release. There is an active ticket on github.com for this issue.